# making threads C2672 and C2893 error code ( c++ )

Tags: c++, c++14

I have trouble compiling this code i get the following messages :

C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found

C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept()'

```
    static auto f = [ ] ( int offset , int step , std::vector<Vert>& vertices , const Transform &transform ) {
        // do stuff
    };

    // create threads

    int max_threads = 4 ;
    std::thread **active_threads = new std::thread * [ max_threads + 1 ] ;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < max_threads ; i++ )
        active_threads [ i ] = new std::thread ( f , i , max_threads , vertices , transform ) ;
```

and this gets the same error as well :

```
    int max_threads = 4 ;

    static auto f = [ ] ( Vert *verts , int offset , int step , const std::vector<Vert> &vertices , const Transform& transform ) {
        // do stuff
    }

    // create threads

    std::vector<std::thread> active_threads ;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < max_threads ; i++ )
        active_threads.push_back ( std::thread ( f , verts , i , max_threads , vertices , transform ) ) ;
```

Compiler : the default vs2019 compiler

Comment: C++14 doesn't have `invoke`, and your code doesn't call it. So... who is? Can you provide an [mcve] along with yoru compiler, standard library, and your compile options?

Comment: Why all the pointers?

Comment: @NicolBolas I use vs2019 ( default c++ compiler ) and std::invoke is called inside the tread header ( c++14 #include <thread> )

Comment: @TedLyngmo the pointers are used so that i have a dynamic std::thread array and being able to make them on the run using a new std::thread();

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector<std::thread>` or  `std::list<std::thread>` for that?

Comment: Read about std::ref and std::cref. Function as thread body (lambda)  takes vectors by references, you have to wrap them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error in VS2019 with C++14. I did however put the references in `std::ref` wrappers, but even without them I didn't get the same error (but a totally different).

My guess is that it's something else in your code that is causing the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

struct Vert {};
struct Transform {};

static auto f = [](int offset, int step, std::vector<Vert>& vertices,
                   const Transform& transform) {
    std::cout << offset << ' ' << step << ' ' << vertices.size() << '\n';
};

int main() {
    std::list<std::thread> active_threads;

    int max_threads = 4;
    std::vector<Vert> vertices;
    Transform transform;

    for(int i = 0; i < max_threads; i++)
        active_threads.emplace_back(f, i, max_threads, std::ref(vertices),
                                    std::ref(transform));

    for(auto& th : active_threads) {
        th.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: std::ref worked , thank you very much I really appreciate it